# simpleXML cloned node position

Tags: php, xml, dom, svg

simpleXML confuses me, still:

I have serious trouble understanding how to set the location where to insert the group... See comment in my code, now I create a copy at the wrong place( g#result1 should be under g#results.

How to change something under this newly created group? (like #twdTextLine0)

How to get the x,y,width,height from #twdBoxStar and put  in its place with the same x,y,width,height and xlink:href="#Star" for example?
At the end  I need to change: svg dimensions, viewbox and the style block, what is the shortest way codewise?

Is there an alternative to simpleXML? maybe where I can get in one line and set in one line? I think someone had to write a class like that.

```
    <?php
    $svg_data = <<<'SVG'
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 20.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="460px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 460 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 460 200;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0{fill:none;stroke:#00FFFF;stroke-width:0.7087;}
      .st1{fill:#FF0000;}
      .st2{font-family:ISOCPEUR, ISOCPEUR;}
      .st3{font-size:37.3524px;}
      .st4{fill:#ED1C24;}
      .st5{font-family:Ebrima-Bold, Ebrima;font-weight: 700;}
      .st6{font-size:68.0315px;}
      .st7{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.7087;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
      .st8{font-size:11.0845px;}
      .st9{font-size:27.6748px;}
      .st10{font-size:18.9881px;}
      .st11{font-size:12px;}
      .st12{font-size:5.6693px;}
      .st13{font-size:9.8585px;}
      .st14{fill:#FF00FF;}
      .st15{fill:#FFFFFF;}
      .st16{font-family:ISOCPEURItalic, ISOCPEUR;font-style: italic;}
      .st17{font-size:12.3452px;}
      .st18{font-size:6.1644px;}
    </style>
    <symbol id="Star" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <path id="Star" style="fill:#00FF00;" d="M50,3.58L62.5,39H100L70.83,60.95l10.42,34.93L50,74.81L18.75,95.53l10.42-34.51L0,39  h37.5L50,3.58z"/>
    </symbol>
    <g id="TemplateForm">
      <g id="twe">
        <rect id="tweCanvas" x="7.3" y="81.32" class="st0" width="263.03" height="72"/>
        <text id="tweWeekdayShorttext" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 247.1745 127.5469)" class="st1 st2 st3">V</text>
        <line id="tweDateNumAliignerRight" class="st0" x1="132.02" y1="89.98" x2="132.02" y2="144.66"/>
        <g id="tweDateNumber">
          <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 132.2695 140.8158)" class="st4 st5 st6">24</text>
        </g>
        <line id="tweDivider" class="st7" x1="126.49" y1="81.32" x2="126.49" y2="153.31"/>
        <g id="tweText">
          <text id="tweTextLine3" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.6379 100.736)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
          <text id="tweTextLine2" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.6379 114.096)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
          <text id="tweTextLine1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.6379 127.4562)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
          <text id="tweTextLine0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.6379 140.8162)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
        </g>
        <rect id="tweBoxMoon" x="216.21" y="121.63" class="st0" width="21" height="21"/>
        <rect id="tweBoxStar" x="216.21" y="92.24" class="st0" width="21" height="21"/>
        <rect id="tweBoxText" x="12.57" y="89.98" class="st0" width="107.92" height="54.68"/>
      </g>
      <g id="twd">
        <rect id="twdCanvas" x="7.3" y="9.32" class="st0" width="263.03" height="72"/>
        <text id="twdWeekdayshorttext" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 249.5817 41.9174)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st2 st3">C</tspan><tspan x="-1.2" y="29.13" class="st2 st3">S</tspan></text>
        <text id="twdDatenumber" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 41.5544 69.5698)" class="st5 st6">26</text>
        <line id="twdDivider" class="st7" x1="126.49" y1="9.32" x2="126.49" y2="81.32"/>
        <g id="twdText">
          <text id="twdTextLine3" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 28.1718)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
          <text id="twdTextLine2" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 41.5319)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
          <text id="twdTextLine1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 54.892)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
          <text id="twdTextLine0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 135.0475 68.252)" class="st2 st8">1234567890abcdef12345</text>
        </g>
        <line id="twdDateNumAliignerLeft" class="st0" x1="120.02" y1="17.39" x2="120.02" y2="72.07"/>
        <rect id="twdBoxStar" x="15.68" y="19.75" class="st0" width="21" height="21"/>
        <rect id="twdBoxText" x="132.49" y="17.39" class="st0" width="107.92" height="54.68"/>
        <rect id="twdBoxMoon" x="15.68" y="49.15" class="st0" width="21" height="21"/>
      </g>
      <g id="tcl">
        <rect id="tclCanvas" x="7.3" y="153.31" class="st0" width="263.03" height="36"/>
        <line id="tclDivider" class="st7" x1="126.49" y1="153.31" x2="126.49" y2="189.31"/>
        <text id="tclYear" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 59.1393 183.5269)" class="st2 st9">YYYY</text>
        <text id="tclMonthname" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 130.9372 182.7798)" class="st2 st10">monthname</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="results">
      <!-- I want to have a copy the whole g#TeplateForm/g#twd with id, attribs and values changed to here in a loop -->
    </g>
    </svg>
    SVG;

    $svg = new SimpleXMLElement($svg_data);
    $svg->registerXPathNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
    $svg->registerXPathNamespace('xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');

    $tType='twd';
    $gTemplate = $svg->xpath('svg:g[@id="TemplateForm"]/svg:g[@id="'.$tType.'"]');
    if (!isset($gTemplate[0])) {
      die("#TemplateForm/#twd group not found\n");
    }
    $gResult = clone $gTemplate[0];
    $gResult['id'] = 'result1';
    $x=40; 
    $y=40;
    $gResult['transform'] = 'matrix(1 0 0 1 '.$x.' '.$y.')';



    $dom_res = dom_import_simplexml($gResult);
    $dom_svg = dom_import_simplexml($svg);
    $dom_svg->appendChild($dom_res);

    echo $svg->asXML();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in this case is that you append the new node to the `svg` document element node. You will need to fetch the `g[@id="results"]` the same way you did the template.

You're already using the alternative - DOM. The main problem with SimpleXML *imho* is that it hides the original DOM nodes. They are still there - that is why you can use `dom_import_simplexml()`.

Rewritten to DOM and fixed your source could look like this:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($svg_data);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
$xpath->registerNamespace('xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');

$tType='twd';
$gTemplate = $xpath->evaluate(
  '/svg:svg/svg:g[@id="TemplateForm"]/svg:g[@id="'.$tType.'"][1]'
);
$gResults = $xpath->evaluate(
  '/svg:svg/svg:g[@id="results"]'
);
if ($gTemplate->length > 0 && $gResults->length > 0) {
  // simplify variables - only the first value from the lists is needed
  $gTemplate = $gTemplate[0];
  $gResults = $gResults[0];

  // possible loop would start here
  $x=40; 
  $y=40;
  // clone the dom nodes with all descendants
  $gResult = $gTemplate->cloneNode(TRUE);
  // change attributes
  $gResult->setAttribute('id', 'result1');
  $gResult->setAttribute('transform', 'matrix(1 0 0 1 '.$x.' '.$y.')');
  $gResults->appendChild($gResult);
  // end loop here 

  echo $document->saveXML();
}
```

`DOMNode::cloneNode()` is a DOM method that clones the node, if the first argument is TRUE, the attribute and descendant nodes are copied as well. The `DOMDocument` has methods to create the different node types or import them from other documents.

`DOMNode::appendChild()` appends the given node as the last child. Here are other methods like `DOMNode::insertChild()`, too.

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return scalar values. You can use it to get values like the viewBox from the Star symbol.

```
var_dump(
  explode(
    " ", 
    $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(//svg:symbol[@id="Star"]/@viewBox)')
  )
);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "100"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "100"
}
```

`normalize-space()` is an Xpath function that transform all whitespace sequences of a string into a single space and trims the result. It includes an implicit string cast. Here is `string()` for an explicit string cast, too.

Comment: Thanks I got the whole thing now, if you add: $node = $xpath->query('svg:g[@id="results"]/svg:g[@id="result1"]/svg:g[@id="twdText"]/svg:text[@id="twdTextLine0"]')->item(0);
$node->textContent="new text";  or something like this to your answer, then the question will be fully answered and I will mark it so, because you helped me a lot it does not feel ethical to answer myself and mark that.

Comment: Actually your answer helped me the most on my research "quest". Thanks